# AspectJ Cannot resolve reference to bean 'selectAll'

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop

Here are classes and xml configuration for Java/AspectJ demo project, but it fails. Project is built in eclipse. I searched on the net, added all libraries but it still fails. Any idea what might be wrong?

UPDATE: These classes were added to eclipse aspectj project:
aopalliance.jar
asm.jar
aspectj.jar
aspectjrt.jar
aspectjtools.jar
aspectjweaver.jar
cglib.jar
org.aspectj.matcher.jar

**class MainApp:**

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Beans.xml");
        Student student = (Student) context.getBean("student");
        student.getName();
        student.getAge();
        student.printThrowException();
    }
}
```

**class Logging:**

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

public class Logging {

    /**
     * This is the method which I would like to execute before a selected method
     * execution.
     */
    public void beforeAdvice() {
        System.out.println("Going to setup student profile.");
    }

    /**
     * This is the method which I would like to execute after a selected method
     * execution.
     */
    public void afterAdvice() {
        System.out.println("Student profile has been setup.");
    }

    /**
     * This is the method which I would like to execute when any method returns.
     */
    public void afterReturningAdvice(Object retVal) {
        System.out.println("Returning:" + retVal.toString());
    }

    /**
     * This is the method which I would like to execute if there is an exception
     * raised.
     */
    public void AfterThrowingAdvice(IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        System.out.println("There has been an exception: " + ex.toString());
    }
}
```

**class Student:**

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

public class Student {
    private Integer age;
    private String name;

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        System.out.println("Age : " + age);
        return age;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        System.out.println("Name : " + name);
        return name;
    }

    public void printThrowException() {
        System.out.println("Exception raised");
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

**Beans.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd ">

   <aop:config>
      <aop:aspect id="log" ref="logging">
         <aop:pointcut id="selectAll" 
         expression="execution(* com.tutorialspoint.*.*(..))"/>
         <aop:before pointcut-ref="selectAll" method="beforeAdvice"/>
         <aop:after pointcut-ref="selectAll" method="afterAdvice"/>
         <aop:after-returning pointcut-ref="selectAll" 
                              returning="retVal"
                              method="afterReturningAdvice"/>
         <aop:after-throwing pointcut-ref="selectAll" 
                             throwing="ex"
                             method="AfterThrowingAdvice"/>
      </aop:aspect>
   </aop:config>

   <!-- Definition for student bean -->
   <bean id="student" class="com.tutorialspoint.Student">
      <property name="name"  value="Zara" />
      <property name="age"  value="11"/>      
   </bean>

   <!-- Definition for logging aspect -->
   <bean id="logging" class="com.tutorialspoint.Logging"/> 

</beans>
```

**Stack trace:**

```
Jan 19, 2017 9:43:02 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@27bc2616: startup date [Thu Jan 19 21:43:02 CET 2017]; root of context hierarchy
Jan 19, 2017 9:43:02 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [Beans.xml]
Jan 19, 2017 9:43:02 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#aec6354' of type [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJMethodBeforeAdvice] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#aec6354': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'selectAll' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'selectAll': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/tools/PointcutPrimitive
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#aec6354' of type [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJMethodBeforeAdvice] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#aec6354': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'selectAll' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'selectAll': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/tools/PointcutPrimitive
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:648)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:145)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1056)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.tutorialspoint.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:8)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#aec6354': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'selectAll' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'selectAll': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/tools/PointcutPrimitive
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:145)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1056)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'selectAll': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/tools/PointcutPrimitive
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1060)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/tools/PointcutPrimitive
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.<clinit>(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1108)
    ... 31 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a long stack trace, but the most relevant part is the `NoClassDefFoundError` near the end:

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/tools/PointcutPrimitive at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:87) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1108) ... 31 more

This indicates the AspectJ classes were not available to the JVM on the runtime classpath.  However this application is invoked, you'll need to ensure that the aspectjweaver.jar file is on the runtime classpath.  For a project managed by Maven, you could specify it as a dependency in pom.xml.  Using purely Eclipse, another option would be to download aspectjweaver.jar (and all of its dependencies) and add it directly to the Eclipse project as an external library.

Comment: These classes were added to eclipse aspectj project:
aopalliance.jar
asm.jar
aspectj.jar
aspectjrt.jar
aspectjtools.jar
aspectjweaver.jar
cglib.jar
org.aspectj.matcher.jar

Comment: I just verified by running `jar tf` that the `org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutPrimitive` class is inside aspectjweaver.jar, which you mentioned you already added.  My best theory is that either it's somehow not making it onto the runtime classpath through the Eclipse configuration, or perhaps it's a version mismatch, such that it's a version of the jar that doesn't really contain the class.

Comment: Probably version mismatch or corrupted libm because I've had both (previously) downloaded libs and then added AJDT (which also has those libs). Anyway I cleared referenced libraries from eclipse, added them back (only from AJDT and now it works. Thanks!